# Find limit of sequence $(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Find limit of sequence $(x_n)$:

$$x_1 = a >0$$
$$x_{n+1} = \frac{n}{2n-1}\frac{x_n^2+2}{x_n}, n \in Z^+$$

I think I can prove $(x_n)$ is low bounded (which is obvious that $x_n>0$) and decreasing sequence. Then I can calculate the limit of sequence is $\sqrt{2}$

All my attempts to prove it's a decreasing sequence have been unsuccessful.

My attemps: Try to prove $x_{n+1}-x_{n} <0$ from a number $N_0$ large enough. It lead to I have to prove $x_n \ge \sqrt{\frac{2n}{n-1}}$ and I stuck.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempts

Comment: @AnneBauval thank u, I edited it

Comment: I saw $\Rightarrow$ +1

Comment: It is more difficult than expected, but I think that I have got it.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer yeahh, Can u write it down? Thank u so much, this exe takes me the whole night

Comment: I have already corrected my answer. Please, remove the downvotes.

Comment: @Jnote, look at my answer now, I have corrected it.

Comment: My idea has failed, not because it's not working but because it's as difficult to execute as the winning argument. I'm dropping it and voting up the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recursion shows that the $x_n$ for $n \ge 2$ are well-defined and bounded below by $\sqrt{2}$, since $x^2+2-2\sqrt{x} = (x-\sqrt{2})^2$ is always positive. Set $y_n = x_n-\sqrt{2}$. Then for $n \ge 2$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
y_{n+1} 
&=& \frac{n(x_n^2+2)-\sqrt{2}(2n-1)x_n}{(2n-1)x_n} \\
&=& \frac{n(x_n-\sqrt{2})^2+\sqrt{2}x_n}{(2n-1)x_n} \\
&=& \frac{ny_n^2}{(2n-1)x_n} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n-1} \\
&\le& \frac{n}{2n-1}y_n+ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2n-1},
\end{eqnarray*} since $y_n \le x_n$.

For $n \ge 2$, $n/(2n-1) \le 2/3$, so
$$y_{n+1} \le \frac{2}{3}y_n+\frac{1}{3}z_n, \text{ where } z_n = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2n-1}$$
Given $\epsilon>0$, one can find an integer $N$ such that for every $n \ge N$, $z_n \le\epsilon$ so $$y_{n+1}-\epsilon \le \frac{2}{3}(y_n-\epsilon),$$
so by recursion
$$y_n-\epsilon \le \Big(\frac{2}{3}\Big)^{n-N}(y_N-\epsilon).$$
As a result, $\limsup_{n \to +\infty} y_n \le \epsilon$. Since this is true for every $\epsilon>0$, we get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Wow, thank u so much. I think in 6th line have small mistake, for $n\ge 2, \frac{n}{2n-1} \le \frac{2}{3}$ (all below is still correct). Thank u so much again

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the typo.

Answer (score 2):

For all $n\ge 1$ is
$$
 x_{n+1} = \frac{2n}{2n-1} \cdot \frac 12 \left( x_n + \frac{2}{x_n} \right) \ge \frac{2n}{2n-1}\sqrt 2 \,,
$$ using the inequality between the arithmetic and the geometric mean. So we have
$$
 x_n^2 \ge 2 \left( \frac{2n-2}{2n-3}\right)^2
$$
for $n \ge 2$. It follows that for $n\ge 2$,
$$
x_{n+1} = \frac{n}{2n-1}\frac{x_n^2+2}{x_n}
 \le \frac{n}{2n-1} \frac{x_n^2 + \left( \frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\right)^2x_n^2}{x_n} = a_n x_n 
$$
with
$$
a_n := \frac{n}{2n-1} \left( 1+ \left( \frac{2n-3}{2n-2}\right)^2\right) 
= \frac{8 n^3 - 20n^2+13n}{8n^2-20n^2+16n - 4} < 1 \, .
$$

This shows that $(x_n)_{n \ge 2}$ is decreasing. It is also bounded below (by zero) and therefore convergent. Now you can take the limit in the recurrence relation and show that the limit is $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think in 6th line: $x_{n+1} = \frac{n}{2n-1}\frac{x_n^2+2}{x_n}$ and $\frac{n}{2n-1} \le \frac{2}{3}$ so $x_{n+1} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{x_n^2+2}{x_n} \le \frac{4}{3}x_n$.

Comment: @Jnote: There was indeed an error, the estimate were too rough. I have updated the answer, hopefully it is correct now!

Answer (score 1):

We will prove that

$\sqrt2<x_{n+1}<x_n\;\;$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;\land\;n\geqslant2\;.\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ it results that

$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=\dfrac n{2n-1}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{x_n^2+2}{x_n}=\dfrac n{2n-1}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{\left(x_n-\sqrt2\right)^2+2\sqrt2x_n}{x_n}\geqslant\\&\geqslant\dfrac{2\sqrt2\,n}{2n-1}>\sqrt2\;.\end{align}$

In particular we get the first inequality of $\,(*)\,$ and we also obtain that

$x_n\geqslant\dfrac{2\sqrt2\,(n-1)}{2n-3}\;\;$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;\land\;n\geqslant2\;.\quad\color{blue}{(1)}$

Moreover, for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;\land\;n\geqslant2\;,\;$ it results that

$2n-(n-1)x_n^2\underset{\color{brown}{(1)}}{\leqslant\;}2n-\dfrac{8(n-1)^3}{(2n-3)^2}=\dfrac{-6n+8}{(2n-3)^2}<0\,.\;\;\color{blue}{(2)}$

For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;\land\;n\geqslant2\;,\;$ it also results that

$\begin{align}x_{n+1}&=\dfrac n{2n-1}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{x_n^2+2}{x_n}=\dfrac{\big[(2n-1)-(n-1)\big]x_n^2+2n}{(2n-1)x_n}=\\&=\dfrac{2n-(n-1)x_n^2+(2n-1)x_n^2}{(2n-1)x_n}\underset{\color{brown}{(2)}}{<}x_n\;.\end{align}$

So we have proved the inequalities $\,(*)\,$, consequently the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded and eventually decreasing, therefore there exists $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=l\in\Bbb R^+\,.$

Moreover ,

$l=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac n{2n-1}\!\cdot\!\dfrac{x_n^2+2}{x_n}\right)=\dfrac{l^2+2}{2l}\;,$

hence ,

$l=\dfrac{l^2+2}{2l}\quad,$

$2l^2=l^2+2\quad,$

$l^2=2\quad,$

$l=\sqrt2\,.$

It means that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\sqrt2\,.$

Comment: You first have to show that the series is bounded above.

Comment: You are right, I am going to correct my answer.

Comment: I have the same idea but I can't prove that the sequence is monotonic. Can you give me some hint

Comment: I have already corrected my answer. Please, take off the downvotes.

Comment: @Fix, I have already corrected my answer.

Comment: @Angelo: I noticed your update only after fixing my solution. It seems that we had similar ideas now. +1 from me!

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are given $x_{n+1} = f_n(x_n)$.  You wanted to show $f_n(x)-x \leq 0$ for all $x \geq \sqrt{2}$, but that's not true.

However, what you *have* shown is that $(x_n)$ can only move away from $\sqrt{2}$ when it's very close to $\sqrt{2}$.  If we ignore for a moment whether it's even possible for $x_n$ to get that close, the question this would raise for me is "how large can the move away from $\sqrt{2}$ even be?"  More precisely, what is the maximum of $f_n(x) - x$ on $\sqrt{2} \leq x \leq \sqrt{2n/(n-1)}$.

Answering this is a simple question of optimization (at least by derivatives if not algebra).  After a bit, we find that maximum is $\sqrt{2}/(2n-1)$ (at $x=\sqrt{2}$), which goes to zero in the limit.

And that would finish it.  You know that outside a diminishing neighborhood of $\sqrt{2}$, the sequence is always decreasing, and if it even were possible to increase, the maximum increase diminishes to $0$.